# Does the Shield spell count as a Shield for Shielded casting?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, shield

I'm 99% certain not, but maybe I'm wrong.
Does the shield spell count as a shield for eg: Shielded casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**

Shielded Casting from *Races of Stone* states:

> As long as you have a light shield, heavy shield, or tower shield ready, ...

The spell [Shield](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/shield.htm) states:

> Shield creates an invisible, tower shield-sized mobile disk of force that hovers in front of you. It negates magic missile attacks directed at you. The disk also provides a +4 shield bonus to AC. This bonus applies against incorporeal touch attacks, since it is a force effect. The shield has no armor check penalty or arcane spell failure chance. Unlike with a normal tower shield, you can’t use the shield spell for cover.

While it creates a force effect the size of a tower shield, the behavior of the disk is otherwise not *like* a tower shield. It simply grants a shield bonus to AC, likely so the caster cannot stack its effect with that of a normal shield.